# how to build a Python dict value from another one during dict creation?

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to build a dict in which one value is built from another.

I thought writing

```
d = {
    'a':1,
    'b':self['a']+1
}
```

but it did not work as expected :

```
>>> {'a':1, 'b':self['a']+1}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

So, how can I achieve that Python trick ? (I'm using Python`2.4`)

Comment: If you already know what value you're setting `'a'` to, then you already have the information that you need to set `'b'`.

Comment: @WayneWerner: but the expression creating the value for `a` could be expensive, you may want to avoid calculating that twice.

Comment: `self` is not a keyword, and has no special meaning anywhere. It's just the conventional name given to the first argument of an instance method.

Comment: @MartijnPieters good point.

Comment: is python 2.4 a typo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't reference a dictionary that has not yet been created. Just assign additional keys *after* creating the dictionary:

```
d = {'a': 1}
d['b'] = d['a'] + 1
```

Alternatively, set the value to a separate variable *first*, then create the dictionary:

```
a_value = 1
d = {'a': a_value, 'b': a_value + 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only have two values, calculate a first, then add b as a separate line.

If the dependencies are more complex, it may be worthwhile to use a function to provide values.

Python 2.7 onwards has dictionary comprehension:

```
mydict = {key: value for (key, value) in iterable}
```

Equivalent in earlier would be:

```
mydict = dict((key, value) for (key, value) in iterable)
```

Now you provide the iterable function for generating the values:

```
def get_dictionary_values():
    a = get_really_expensive_calculation()
    yield ('a', a)
    b = a + modification_value
    yield ('b', b)
    # Add all other values here that calculate from earlier values.

mydict = dict((key, value) for (key, value) in get_dictionary_values())
```

With options of loops inside the function as needed.